# replacing a dot in a time string with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace a time string like: "18.00" or "18.00/23.00" with "18:00" and "18:00/23:00".

Now i've made something, but it's not working and i'm not that experienced with this

```
preg_replace("/\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}/","$1:$2","18.00/23.00");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add capturing parentheses and escape the dot:

```
echo preg_replace("/(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2})/","$1:$2","18.00/23.00");
                    ^       ^^ ^       ^
```

See [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/5croFf).

The `$1` and `$2` are [*backreferences*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) that point to the contents captured with [*capturing groups*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php) instead

```
str_replace(".", ":",$your_date);
```

Comment: This might produce unwanted replacements. For example, if you changed the string to be `See you at the normal time. 18.00/23.00`. With Wiktor's answer it would work still but for yours, the `.` would be converted as well to be `See you at the normal time: 18:00/23:00`

Comment: you're right, but op just ask about a time string like 18.00, nether less he had to be careful about that

Comment: True but the regex with `(\d{1,2})` suggests it's specifically for a colon following 1 or 2 digits.